# Regarding Php ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi i'm trying to make a php applications, on html page i'm using

```html
<div id="lt1" style="display: none;">
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div id="popupContact">
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form action="index.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<img id="close" src="images/3.png" onclick ="div_hidelt1()">
<h2>chk style</h2>
<hr>
<input type="url" name="url" value="" placeholder="Enter URL to Analyze..." maxlength="2048" >
<button style="width: -webkit-fill-available;" type="submit">Analyze</button>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
<button id="popup" onclick="div_showlt1()">page load time</button>
```

and have a php code on same page to print result of function but there are lots of function and i want to call all of them on same page so i want to use ajax for the same can some help me out here how to do this :( Thanx

Comment: Please provide more detailed information, maybe some PHP Code. So you are trying to call a function on index.php? You could create a hidden field called "action" and read it in index.php so you know which function to call

Comment: `php applications, on html page i'm using`-> no you can't because a `.html` extension will never execute php code. Change your file extension to `.php` and it will handle both html+php itself. After that try to ask the question with some more input code (php code) and exactly what's your problem and where you face issue.

Comment: if a code.php file where all the functions are written like this one public function get_description() {
$tags = get_meta_tags($this->url);
$tag_count = strlen(htmlspecialchars_decode($tags['description']));
$desc = array('meta_desc' => $tags['description']);
$desccount = array('meta_desc_count' => $tag_count);
$descarray = $desc + $desccount;
return $descarray;
}   and i want to show the results of various function on same page